# MUI DatePicker disablePast/disableFuture grayed out not working when views={['year', 'month']}

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using a disableFuture or a disablePast prop for the MUI datePicker does not result in grayed out dates when also using mm/yy.  Dates gray out as expected with mm/dd/yy but not with mm/yy. Not sure why MUI would limit the mm/yy look.  Am I missing something?

```
 <DatePicker
   label='Date'
   fieldName='date'
   views={['year', 'month']}
   required
   disableFuture
/>
```

[image: Dates are not grayed out when view is mm/yy]

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be an issue as well when you are using the `views{[]}` parameter ..  The way I got around it was using `minDate` and `maxDate`

```
// Set as today for maxDate
maxDate = {new Date()}

<DatePicker
    label='Date'
    fieldName='date'
    views={['year', 'month']}
    required
    minDate={...} // your minDate if applicable
    maxDate={new Date()}  //maxDate
/>
```

Then MUI will only allow dates in that "range".  I use npm's `dayjs` to make it easier .. Something like:

```
minDate={dayjs('2022-04-01')}
maxDate={dayjs('2023-04-01')}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This did work by omitting the options rather than graying them out.  I was hoping for grayed out but I might use this solution if need be.  Thanks for your input .